# How to implement a website where the URL doesn't change when you click internal links?

Tags: html, url, frames

How do some website implement URL addresses that don't change when you click on an internal link? So if, for example, the URL is `www.example.com` it remains exactly that if you clicked on the "contact" link of that site. Also when I go to my site it changes to `www.example.com/home.html` but some other site remain `www.example.com`.

Comment: The URL doesn't change because the site is badly designed :) (I'll leave the technical explanations to the answers below)

Answer (score 4):

The probably just use frames or iframes. The outer frame on `www.example.com` stays in place while the inner frame points to `www.example.com/home` or whatever.

Comment: Please consider that doing so is bad practice, as it prevents unsavy users from bookmarking subpages, which is frustrating and will result in less visitors over time.

Comment: It also doesn't work when search engines direct people to pages inside the site.

Answer (score 1):

Other options include AJAX or JavaScript implementations.

For instance, with AJAX you can load dynamic information into an element (such as a DIV) without causing the page to reload.

The same can be said of using other JavaScript functionality, for instance hiding and showing elements on the page via an onclick event attached to a link.

As Martin said above, this sort of functionality is definitely considered to be bad practice.  You essentially kill any sort of site structure that either a user or search spider will be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple iframe example([demo](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/42655/eternity/cnn.html)):

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>CNN</title> 
    <style type="text/css">       
      html, body, iframe {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        overflow: hidden; }
      iframe { overflow: auto; }
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <iframe src="http://www.cnn.com/"></iframe> 
  </body>
</html>
```

As others have already stated this is a bad practice.